# How do I add references to C#?

Tags: assembly-references

I need to  upload programmatically  files to sharepoint. I read many artiles how to do this . However, apparently my computer does not have most of the references preinstalled. For example I was not able to find anywhere in the reference list such things as `Microsoft.SharePoint;` , `SPSite`, `SPWeb`, `SPList` , `DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging` ...

So, where do I get this packages and how can I add them ?

I understand these references similar to `jar` files in Java. Where can I download missing references

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to SharePoint 2010, then the packages can be downloaded here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=21786

The SharePoint 2013 packages can be downloaded at:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35585